Deploy multiple GPO's for Onedrive configurations with Microsoft Intune giving conflict
I am having problems with deploying Sharepoint configuration for multiple libraries. In Intune I have configured multiple administrative template policies for OneDrive.
The configuration "Configure team site libraries to sync automatically" is configured. When I deploy the same configuration with a different name (for a different site) it is giving a conflict. Intune is not able to deploy both configurations or add multiple configurations to one user/device.
The reason that I do it this way has to do with different permissions. Every configuration has its own Entra ID group. When someone is member of two groups, he will get two configurations deployed, but in this case it is giving a conflict error and the configurations cannot be applied.
Is this a known issue or is this something that I can configure from Intune?
